# SCons build with development gcc8

Tags: python, build, mongodb

I'm attempting to build MongoDB v4.0 on CentOS7 (https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source), and am unfamiliar with the python toolset included for building. The toolset requires gcc8.2 or newer, which I have installed with `devtoolset-8-gcc` and `devtoolset-8-g++`. I enable the toolset using `scl enable devtoolset-8 bash` And execute the scons build following the build guide, however scons appears to build its own environment which doesnt include the library at `/opt/rh/devtoolset-8/`.

```
[user@localhost mongo.git]$ sudo scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
[sudo] password for user:
[root@localhost mongo.git]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3)
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
[root@localhost mongo.git]# ./buildscripts/scons.py
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 2.5.0
python version: 2 7 5 'final' 0
...
Checking if C compiler is GCC 8.2 or newer...no
Checking if C++ compiler is GCC 8.2 or newer...no
ERROR: Refusing to build with compiler that does not meet requirements
See /opt/mongodb/mongo.git/build/scons/config.log for details
```

The log file contents are available at https://pastebin.com/jB2q4NxN.

My attempts to modify the python script to include the path per the scons manual have netted another error:

```
[root@localhost mongo.git]# buildscripts/scons.py all
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "buildscripts/scons.py", line 7, in <module>
    env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
NameError: name 'Environment' is not defined
```

After I added the lines

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = {'PATH' : os.environ['PATH']})
```

To my `buildscripts/scons.py` file. Am I adding this in the wrong place perhaps?  Why is the environment variable not available?

Thanks.

Comment: You are already logged in as root, so `sudo` is unnecessary and will change to a new environment. You should be able to build fine as a normal (non-root) user or without `sudo`. There should be no need to modify the MongoDB build scripts; this is a hint that you're probably taking an incorrect approach.

Comment: Hi Stennie. Good catch, thanks, but the same error remains.

`[user@localhost mongo.git]$ sudo scl enable devtoolset-8 bash
[sudo] password for user:
[root@localhost mongo.git]# ./buildscripts/scons.py
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons version: 2.5.0
python version: 2 7 5 'final' 0
...
Checking if C compiler is GCC 5.3.0 or newer...no
Checking if C++ compiler is GCC 5.3.0 or newer...no
ERROR: Refusing to build with compiler that does not meet requirements
See /opt/mongodb/mongo.git/build/scons/config.log for details`

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `/opt/mongodb/mongo.git/build/scons/config.log ` (or a link to pastebin/gist if it's too large to include inline)?

Comment: I have added a link. It appears to just reiterate the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just name the path to the compiler with the CC and CXX Variables on the SCons command line:

`scons CC=/path/to/toolset/gcc CXX=/path/to/toolset/g++`

Please note however, that GCC 8 is not officially supported for building MongoDB 4.0. You may find that it doesn't build, or that it builds with warnings that are promoted to errors. You can work around some of them by adding the flag `--disable-warnings-as-errors` to your SCons invocation.

The reason you don't see the environment variables in your build is that SCons by default ignores the users environment in the interest of producing reproducible builds. If you really want to let SCons see the current shell environment, you can add `--variables-files=etc/scons/propagate_shell_environment.vars` to your SCons invocation.

Comment: Thanks acm this seems to have gotten past the issue.

The git page wiki says that gcc8.2 is essential, as does the install from mongodb source, so it doesn't make sense to me that gcc8 would not be supported? I'm not using gcc8 by choice, it appears mandatory...

Comment: @gangr33n - Which git wiki page?

Comment: The one I included at the start of my post. https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/wiki/Build-Mongodb-From-Source

Comment: @gangr33n - Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately, the github wiki doesn't track the versions of the server, so it can only ever reflect the build situation on the master branch. Older branches have different requirements. You may do better to review the BUILDING.md file for the branch of interest. For MongoDB 4.0, that is https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v4.0/docs/building.md